# Cloud Run error: "Error 403 (Forbidden)!!" when sending many request at once Posted yes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm facing an issue with a cloud run service. It works fine, I send request and receive responses but when I try sending a lot of requests almost 40/s it fails with this message received by the client :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=en>\n  <meta charset=utf-8>\n  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">\n  <title>Error 403 (Forbidden)!!1</title>\n  <style>\n    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}\n  </style>\n  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>\n  <p><b>403.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>\n  <p>Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/api/decrypt</code> from this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>\n
```

The message doesn't appear into the cloud run service logs. I only have it as response.

My maximum number of concurrent requests that can reach each instance is at 1000 and the number of request sent is aproximately 40-45.

Do you have an idea of what could be my issue?

Thank you in advance.
Best regards,

As I said beofre, I can make requests so it's not really about service account permissions or whatever. It's only when I send many requests at simultanously that I get that answer.

So I tried again single requests. They were successful. I increased the **maximum number of concurrent requests that can reach each instance**, **minimum instances**, the **number of cpu** per instance, the **memory size** also but nothing.

I don't see at all how to fix this

Comment: Does the traffic come from the same IP?

Comment: Not at all, it comes from differents IP addresses